# Warning on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to define an `EditText` but this warning is shown:

```
This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint.
```

The code in `main.xml` is:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/input" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="@string/textTest" />
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: For more information on inputType, check these docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could add a `hint` :

```
android:hint="This will appear to the user if he didn't enter something yet in the EditText"
```

and a `inputType` so you could present to the user a better suited soft keyboard for the text he is suposed to enter in the `EditText`:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

will present a soft keyboard with only numbers and various signs.
Those are just warnings, you could ignore them but is better for the user to implement them.

Answer (score 6):

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:inputType="text"
        >
```

I think You should add input type.......

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. Sometimes it doest work with changing to:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

I got it to work by setting:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Above all are the solutions but before that you should understand what does that warnig mean.

**Hint:-** Hint is the text shown to user before writing anything over. 
           For eg. if you are putting a edittext where you want user to add his
           name then you can write

```
<Edittext
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:hint="Enter Name"/>
```

**Input Type:-** This is the xml tag that is to be used within edittext to let edittext to follow that particular restriction. if you are giving inputtype:number then user would be able to enter only numbers. There are several input type fields are there for that you can refer official developer site.