# No resource found that matches the given name at layout_hint

Tags: android, xml, sdk

I am new in fact this is my first attempt to android program. I am following the android developers training website. My `activity_main.xml` looks like following :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_hint="@string/edit_message"/>
```

Now it shows an error and warning like:

Warning - `This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint`

Error - `error:Error:No resource found that matches the given name( at 'layout_hint' with the value '@string/edit_message')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define the value of `edit_message` in `res/values/strings.xml` file. As for the warning, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436213/warning-on-edittext).

Comment: Thanks a lot..the error is gone now. But I am still getting the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

not android:layout_hint="@string/edit_message"

but android:hint="@string/edit_message"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried all ways and this it what I found.

If I typed :

```
 android:layout_hint="@string/edit_message"
```

This was in red :

```
"@string/edit_message"
```

but if I typed :

```
android:layout_hint=" @string/edit_message"
```

( note the Space after the first " )
then this changed to green :

```
" @string/edit_message"
```

This worked for me.